# Passing props to Modal (React Native)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to pass a prop to a modal screen from a Flatlist, i have tried all possible means to get this done, but i didnt seem to understand it. when i try to pass props, it says that it cant update a state to a readonly property

**Here is the useEffect and useState**

```
const [proops, setProops] = useState([]);
const [passedProps, setPassedProps] = useState('');

 useEffect(() => {
     const onChildAdd = database().ref('/User/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
   
       const props= [];
       snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
       const id = userSnapshot.key;
       const userData = userSnapshot.val();
       
       userData['uid'] = id;
       proops.push(userData);
       
       });
       setProops(proops);
        
       
       });
       
           
        return () =>
           database().ref('/User/' )
               .off('value', onChildAdd);
       
   
   }, [props])
```

**This is the Flatlist**

```
       <FlatList
data={proops}
ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Divider />}
keyExtractor={item => item.id}
ListEmptyComponent={() => <ActivityIndicator/> }
renderItem={({ item }) => (
<View style={{flex: 1,  width: '100%', justifyContent: 'flex-start',  alignItems: 'center', color: 'black'}}>

<View style={{flex: 18,  width: '100%', justifyContent: 'flex-start', color: 'black'}}>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
  
>
        <List.Item title={item.Name} description='Click to open the modal' 
          titleNumberOfLines={1}
    titleStyle={styles.listTitle}
    descriptionStyle={styles.listDescription}
    descriptionNumberOfLines={1}
    onPress={() => setPassedProps(item.Name)}
        />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      
      
</View>
</View>
)}
/>
```

**Here is the modal**

```
 <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{ ...styles.openButton, backgroundColor: "#2196F3" }}
              onPress={() => {
                setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
              }}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        <Text>{passedProps}</Text>    
</View>
</View>
)}
/>
 </View>
</View>
      </Modal>
```

**Error**

*TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. *

**it happens when i tap an item from the flatlist**
[image: it happens when i tap an item from the flatlist]

Comment: it would help if you also give us the name of the readonly property

Comment: the problem is coming from onPress={() => setPassedProps(item.Name)}

Comment: add a SS of the error?

Comment: in the <List.item> of the flalist

Comment: i don't think it has anything to do with your modal. Check your firebase code to see what you are doing with the snapshot.

Comment: the code works fine if i remove onPress={() => setPassedProps(item.Name)}

Comment: but if i remove it, i wont be able to pass props to the modal

Comment: can you show the code for setPassedProps? also the relevant firebase code that deals with its snapshots?

Comment: i have added it

Answer (score 1):

the problem might be that you are adding too many listeners. Should only add the listener once the components loads.

```
useEffect(() => {
     const onChildAdd = database().ref('/User/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
   
       //const props= []; <<< not sure why you would want to do this.
       snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
       const id = userSnapshot.key;
       const userData = userSnapshot.val();
       
       userData['uid'] = id;
       proops.push(userData);
       
       });
       setProops(proops);
       });
       
           
        return () =>
           database().ref('/User/' )
               .off('value', onChildAdd);
   }, []) // <<< you want to just add one listener for your list of user. [] means only run this once when component mounts.
```

Comment: i added the top declaration to prevent rendering that adds to the new list, instead, when there is a change, it erases the former list and sets a new list

Comment: why do you want to remove the whole list instead of just render the new items?